# How do I calculate the time difference in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter

I have a model with two TimeFields. I want to show the time difference in a template (ie, 27 minutes). I see the filter timesince, but it isn't working; I think it only accepts datetimes but my models have stored times only.

Response to @HAL:

```
'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'year'
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\timesince.py in timesince, line 32
```

Comment: What sort of error are you receiving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only compare two time stamps if you know their corresponding dates and timezones.. The `datetime.time` class contains only the time. I strongly advise you to consider using a `DateTimeField` (which uses `datetime.datetime`) in this case.

If you are sure that both `datetime.time` objects are having the same date and timezone, then you can add method to your model like this:

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timesince import timesince

class MyModel(models.Model):
...

    def get_time_diff(self):
        dummydate = datetime.date(2000,1,1)  # Needed to convert time to a datetime object
        dt1 = datetime.combine(dummydate,self.t1)
        dt2 = datetime.combine(dummydate,self.t2)
        return timesince(dt1, dt2)   # Assuming dt2 is the more recent time
```

Here the time values are upgraded to a datetime value using an arbitrary date. You can invoke this from the template as `{{ obj.get_time_diff }}`.

Comment: thanks. I corrected the import lines in your answer. For others, I used this code in a custom template filter that mimics timesince so that it can be used generically for any time objects.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)  template tag.